# Append one layer to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, append

I am a long time user of various GIS packages and am starting to explore QGIS in more detail.  I have a polyline shapefile with some multipart features.  I did not create the shapefile, but must edit it to fix the multipart features - they need to exist as single part features.  Its easy enough to run the Topology Checker and create a "must not have multi-part geometries" rule to identify the problematic features.  Its also easy enough to select the offending features and run the "Multipart to singleparts" tool to get single part features.

I noticed that the default output is set to [Create temporary layer].  Is there a way to set the output as the original layer instead of creating a temporary layer?  If not, then what is the "normal" process for appending the layer containing the single parts into the original layer that had the multipart features?  Naturally before I would append the temporary layer, I would delete the multipart feature from the original layer.

Comment: you can also use the advanced tools to do your multi-part fixes https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#advanced-digitizing and you can copy and paste features into one layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since v3.4, QGIS supports **In Place Editing**. That means you can now make changes to individual objects within the source layer.

- Select multipart geometries.
- Type tool name (`Multipart to singleparts`) in Locator bar (search box) in the status bar.
- Double click the tool you need under `Edit Selected Features`. After double clicking the tool, all multipart geometries are converted to singleparts within the source layer. That means you don't need an extra appending process.

[image]